# I want to send a notification from my PHP application to my android app

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to send notification from PHP application and same time it should be received by android application. I have no idea about it. I just know i do not want to use thread to be schedule for seconds and call url but get activate when notification sends from PHP server.

Comment: use a socket connection between your php script and your android app. simple.

Comment: Please give me a glance of it as i have no idea about this. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You required to use Android Cloud to Device Messaging C2DM API of Android,

Please find a useful example from [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html).